# Multiple Django projects under the same URL

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, port

I have two separate Django projects running on a Amazon EC2, that have different databases and use different settings files.

To do this, I use Nginx, that for the `project1` listens at port `80` (url www.domain.com) and for the `project2` listens at port `81` (url www.domain.com:81).

Using my website at some places, I noticed that `project2` was excessively slow, due to maybe some networks block requests to specific ports.

So, I just want to use both projects with port `80`. Is it possible, maybe with a different URL after the ".com"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible.

Take a look at Nginx 'Server Blocks' to accomplish this...
http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample

The caveat is that I don't believe it's possible to create 'Server Blocks' and route based on "different URL after the ".com"?"  To be technically correct, it would be the URL path after the .com.

However, if you have different 'server names' (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) than you could set up different 'server blocks' to handler requests to different Django applications running on the same box.

Say for instance you have Application1 using domain 'foo.com' and Application2 using domain 'bar.com'.  A typical setup would look like,

```
http {
  index index.html;

  server {
    server_name foo.com;
    access_log logs/application1.access.log main;

    root /var/www/application1.com/htdocs;
  }

  server {
    server_name bar.com;
    access_log  logs/application2.access.log main;

    root /var/www/application2.com/htdocs;
  }
}
```

Just make sure both foo.com and bar.com point to your server running the Django apps.

You could use subdomains too if you'd like... app1.foo.com, app2.foo.com... both are valid server_name values.